# How can I put my WAMP server online to access my localhost projects through Internet?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, localhost

I would like to put my WAMP server online so that my localhost projects could be accessed through Internet. I tried and followed various tutorials on the web but nothing worked for me. I also went through with [How to put online your WampServer](http://www.simonewebdesign.it/how-to-put-online-your-wampserver/) but it also didn't work for me. I have already done "Put Online" in WAMP tray icon. I am running Windows 7 SP 1 Ultimate. I don't have any wireless router.

I am accessing Internet using hotspot of my smartphone. I remember when I had have Windows XP SP3 and old version of WAMP (I think WAMP5 1.7.4) then it was very easy to put server online. I used to get my IP address. Put server online. And then could access my localhost through Internet by using the same IP. There is nothing to deal with port forwarding thing.

I guess do I need to do something with port forwarding. But as per my condition (Win7, WAMP 2.5, Mobile Intenet, No rounter), what settings or configuration I need to do to access localhost through Internet? Can anyone explain in simple words and could provide me working solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the phone is creating a LAN when you say you are creating an hotspot with it, so you do have a router it's your phone.

In simple words you need to do two things.

1. **make the web service accessible from your LAN** 
   You can check this by using another device connected to the hotspot, and trying to access

`<private IP address of server>:<port used by the server>`,

ex `192.168.1.3:8080`

2. **check your hotspot is redirecting the traffic from "the outside" to your local server.** This is the tricky part, it's going to depend on your mobile phone etc

If using a android phone mabe check this out:
[link to google play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.bherbst.net&hl=en)

Then check from another device connected to the internet:

`<public IP address>:<Public Port configured to be forwarded>`,

Comment: oh its seems to be too complicated for me. not following it properly. sorry!

Comment: Ok no problem. Start telling me about your phone's hotspot. How are you sharing your phone's internet connection ? Did you create a WiFi hotspot with your phone, it's a direct USB connection  or Bluetooth ? @user3779493

Comment: Its a smartphone. I am accessing phone's Internet by hotspot wi-fi tethering.

Comment: An android smarphone? Then your phone does create a LAN on the WIFI network, the phone acts also as your router. Try step 1 using a 3rd device (another phone, tablet or computer) connected to that same hotspot and try to connect to your website using the ***local*** ip address and port on a webrowser  (you can get the local IP address of your server with an ipconfig command on a windows terminal)

Comment: I tried but I'm getting "Unable to connect" in Firefox.

Comment: Is your web server is running in your localhost? (meaning you can access it locally by using http://127.0.0.1:80)  If the anser is yes, then you should redo the part called ***Configuring the server to be reachable by everyone*** from the tutorial you attached on the question.

Comment: No I can't. It says "Forbidden".

Comment: Did you put it online? It can be done by just clicking on the green WampServer tray icon and choosing “Put Online”

Comment: It was already Online. But still didn't work. I don't know what needs to be done and how? Its getting complicated every time.

Comment: I guess the service is not really up, and the port giving the web services is not open. Try doing a netstat -an in the cmd just to be sure if the web port is open or not, you should see a line like ***TCP 127.0.0.1:80 .... ... LISTENING*** or ***TCP 127.0.0.1:8080 .... ... LISTENING***

Answer (score 0):

For Wamp 3 (Apache 2.4), besides putting the server online as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19588786/1225421), if you still get 403 (Access Denied) response from Apache, then in the Virtual Hosts file `conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`
you might need to replace

```
Require local
```

with

```
Require all granted
```

This is applicable if in `httpd.conf` you have

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Comment: But I am using WampServer2.5